validation rule for File using yup in vee-validate
I have a simple form using vue3 & vuetify3. I am trying to incorporate vee-validate to validate my form.
But the compiler is not happy about file.size and file.type. Any help is much appreciated
interface FormModel {
  name?: string | null;
  email?: string | null;
  phone?: string | null;
  address?: string | null;
  resume?: File | null;
}

const supportedFileFormats = ref([
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
  'application/pdf'
]);

const maxFileSize = ref(20 * 1024 * 1024);

const { errors, handleSubmit, handleReset, defineField } = useForm<FormModel>({
  validationSchema: toTypedSchema(object(
    {
      name: string()
        .required('Name is required'),

      email: string()
        .email('Invalid email format')
        .required('Email is required')
        .test('customError', (currentValue, context) => {
          return currentValue && currentValue.startsWith('_')
            ? context.createError({ message: `${customEmailErrorMessage.value}`, path: 'email' })
            : true;
        }),

      phone: string()
        .matches(/^(?:\+?61|0)4(?:[ -]?\d){8}$/, 'Phone must be in Aus mobile format')
        .required('Phone is required'),

      address: string()
        .optional(),

      resume: mixed()
        .nullable()
        .required('Resume is required')
        .test('fileSize', 'Maximum file size allowed is 20MB', (file) => {
          return !file || (file && file.size <= maxFileSize.value);
        })
        .test('fileType', 'Allowed file types are .docx, .pdf', (file) => {
          return !file || (file && supportedFileFormats.value.includes(file.type));
        }),
    }))
});

